# How to Deploy same Wsp files with same name to Different Webapplication in same server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, solution-deployment

In sharepoint 2016 server i was created two web applications.In first web app i 
installed wsp files.Site was working withou any issues.

In wsp fiels some of the files as "Web" scoped. some of the wsp files "Site" scoped.

Using that same wsp fiels, in site definition i changed the Template ID.
I installed all the wsp to 2nd wep application.

Now the 2nd webapplication site was working.But 1st web application site throwing following error.

[image]

Comment: Do you try to use PowerShell to install the same WSp on all web application *without specifying the web application parameter* or -AllWebApplications  ? Also if you have DLL files in the bin of the first web application, try to move it in the bin of the second web application

Comment: how to move dll to second web application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy (Add -Install) the same WSP for all SharePoint web applications in the farm by using `-AllWebApplications` parameter in `Install-SPSolution` cmdlet as the following:

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\Solution\SP_solution.wsp"    
Install-SPSolution -Identity SP_solution.wsp -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment
```

> If you have DLL files in the bin folder of the first web application that related to this solution, try to copy it in the bin folder of the
>   second web application.

**For more details check**

- [Install-SPSolution.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Install and deploy a SharePoint (WSP) solution package using SharePoint shell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)

Comment: if i use -AllWebApplications it will deployed in all the web applications.I want to deploy only 2 web applications.

Comment: In same site definition  i changed the templated ID and name.But in templates its displaying new name.Old site template name get removed.